# What is meant in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

they would have slain Hodur there and then, were it not that killing was not permitted in asgard, not that loki paid any attention to that rule.

Comment: It's "slain Hodur *there and then**"

Comment: They did not kill Hodur because killing was forbidden in Asgard. (Even so, Loki usually ignored that rule.)

Comment: What does "were it not that ... not that " mean ?

Comment: The "were it" is a continuation of the subjunctive mood of "they would have". The "not that" is another clause (which Kate parenthesised, and made into a separate sentence) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They would have

They wanted to, but did not...

> slain Hodur there and then

...kill Houdur on the spot, without taking the time to discuss the matter or formally charge him or put him on trial...
(note that I usually hear the phrase as *then and there* not *there and then*)

> were it not that killing was not permitted in Asgard

...but killing was not allowed...

> not that Loki paid any attention to that rule.

...although Loki didn't follow the rule against killing.

---

As Weather Vane said, "would have... were it not that..." is a construction that explains what someone **wanted** or **intended** to do, and then describes the reason they **did not** do it. The second "...not that" is a separate clause altogether, describing what someone did/does despite it being against the rules or custom. Taken as a whole, this sentence tells the reader that:

- Asgard has a rule against killing
- People in Asgard follow this rule, even when they are angry enough that they want to kill someone without a trial
- Loki is different from other people in Asgard, because he does not follow this rule.